# ClassNotFoundException com. mysql . jdbc . Driver

Tags: java, eclipse, mysql-connector, classnotfound

With eclipse and my sql.connector-java-8.0.28.jar in libraries Classpath correct location, the eclipse error is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com. mysql . jdbc . Driver

The .jar is localition than indicates de classpath

Help me, please!!
Thank yo

Help me, i dont understand, the .jar is in de location and i can see in the reference libraries of Project Explorer the mysql - connector - java.

Comment: Don't load the class. Just `DriverManager.getConnection` But we need to see your code

Comment: If you have a `module-info.java` file, does deleting it help? Otherwise, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: fwiw the driver class for that version is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` (not that this needs to be known, *or used*)

Comment: In your question you have whitespace in various positions where I would not expect them. Is it the same in your code/configuration? Take a closer look.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.